# Preselect items in EXT JS 4.2 Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-grid

I am trying to preselect items in my EXT grid based on the value of one of the items in the data store.

In my data store I fetch 7 items, the last item I grab 'installed' is a BOOLEAN and I would like to use that to preselect items in my grid.

Here is the code I have so far that is not working...

```
Ext.require([
  'Ext.grid.*',
  'Ext.data.*',
  'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'
]);

Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.QuickTips.init();

var sb = $('#sb_id').val();

// Data store
var data =  Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: [ 'name', 'market', 'expertise', 'id', 'isFull', 'isPrimary', 'installed'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/opsLibrary/getLibraryJsonEdit',
        extraParams: {
            sb_id: sb
        },
        actionMethods: 'POST'
    },
    sorters: [{
        property: 'market',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }, {
        property: 'expertise',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});

data.on('load',function(records){
    Ext.each(records,function(record){

        var recs = [];
        Ext.each(record, function(item, index){

            console.log(item.data);
            if (item.data['installed'] == true) {
                console.log('Hi!');
                recs.push(index);
            }
        });
        //data.getSelectionModel().selectRows(recs);
    })
});

// Selection model
var selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    columns: [
        {xtype : 'checkcolumn', text : 'Active', dataIndex : 'id'}
    ],
    listeners: {
        selectionchange: function(value, meta, record, row, rowIndex, colIndex){
            var selectedRecords = grid4.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
            var selectedParams = [];

            // Clear input and reset vars
            $('#selected-libraries').empty();
            var record = null;
            var isFull = null;
            var isPrimary = null;

            // Loop through selected records
            for(var i = 0, len = selectedRecords.length; i < len; i++){
                record = selectedRecords[i];

                // Is full library checked?
                isFull = record.get('isFull');

                // Is this primary library?
                isPrimary = record.get('isPrimary');

                // Build data object
                selectedParams.push({
                    id: record.getId(),
                    full: isFull,
                    primary: isPrimary
                });
            }
            // JSON encode object and set hidden input
            $('#selected-libraries').val(JSON.stringify(selectedParams));
        }}
});
```

I was trying to use an on.load method once the store was populated to go back and preselect my items but am not having any luck.

Im a Python guy and don't get around JS too much so sorry for the noobness.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
//create selModel instance above
data.on('load', function(st, recs) {
    var installedRecords = Ext.Array.filter(recs, function(rec) {
        return rec.get('installed');
    });

    //selModel instance
    selModel.select(installedRecords);
});
```

Select can take an array of records.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-select

```
//data.getSelectionModel().selectRows(recs);
```

Didn't work because store's don't have a reference to selection models it is the other way around.  You can get a selection model from a grid by doing grid.getSelectionModel() or 
you can just use the selModel instance you created

```
var selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
```

Comment: That worked beautifully and thank you very much for going the extra step and explaining where I went wrong.